# Create Attribute set in Magento 2 using Api

Tags: magento2, rest-api, attribute-set

I am trying to create an attribute set and assign multiple attribute into it using `rest api` in `Magento2`.
Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magento 2 already have an API point for creating an attribute set.

```
http://www.example.com/rest/V1/products/attribute-sets
```

You have to hit API point

**and have to post below value**

```
    {
  "attributeSet": {
    "attribute_set_name": "TESTAMIT",
    "sort_order": 10,
    "entity_type_id": 4
  },
  "skeletonId": 4
}
```

Here ,here

- skeletonId is the attribute set id on which your new   attribute set
  `TESTAMIT` build. Here 4 is Magento default attribute set `Default` Id
- "entity_type_id": 4  ,Here 4 products entity type id. Most of the time,  when you want to build a new build that time system asking which attributes structure will you want to follow.

### Example at CURL

```
curl -X POST \
  http://www.example.com/rest/V1/products/attribute-sets \
  -H 'authorization: Bearer p0jc2h1jwpha6gmje34frq9dm7x9liv4' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'postman-token: 33e5dccd-7776-e22b-1a24-b484473cbe86' \
  -d '{
  "attributeSet": {
    "attribute_set_name": "TESTAMIT",
    "sort_order": 10,
    "entity_type_id": 4
  },
  "skeletonId": 4
}'
```

### PHP CURL

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://www.example.com/rest/V1/products/attribute-sets",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\n  \"attributeSet\": {\n    \"attribute_set_name\": \"TESTAMIT\",\n    \"sort_order\": 10,\n    \"entity_type_id\": 4\n  },\n  \"skeletonId\": 4\n}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "authorization: Bearer p0jc2h1jwpha6gmje34frq9dm7x9liv4",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: application/json",
    "postman-token: 10353b40-630e-ab82-849b-d6a23d7a52b2"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Comment: can you explain a bit more on skeletonId,entity_type_id

Comment: @Amit, is any api for creating attribute?